# Mismatch in time in Windows while dualbooting

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, grub, ubuntu-14.04

I installed 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside my Windows 7 OS in my MSI GX70. I found that my Windows time is always 2 hours ahead of the actual time. My Ubuntu version shows the correct time. So I tried fixing it using the instructions posted in this link. However, I reboot and the problem persists. Are there other ways to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem.  Windows uses local time by default and Ubuntu uses UTC.

Here is an [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts) explaining how to resolve the issue a few different ways.

**Multiple Boot Systems Time Conflicts**

Operating systems store and retrieve the time in the hardware clock located on your motherboard so that it can keep track of the time even when the system does not have power. Most operating systems (Linux/Unix/Mac) store the time on the hardware clock as UTC by default, though some systems (notably Microsoft Windows) store the time on the hardware clock as the 'local' time. This causes problems in a dual boot system if both systems view the hardware clock differently.

The advantage of having the hardware clock as UTC is that you don't need to change the hardware clock when moving between timezones or when Daylight Savings Time (DST) begins or ends as UTC does not have DST or timezone offsets.

Changing Linux to use local time is easier and more reliable than changing Windows to use UTC, so dual-boot Linux/Windows systems tend to use local time.

Since Intrepid (8.10), UTC=yes is default.

**Make Windows use UTC**

**Note**: This method was not initially supported on Windows Vista and Server 2008, but came back with Vista SP2, Windows 7, Server 2008 R2 and Windows 8/8.1.

To make MS Windows calculate the time from the hardware clock as UTC.

Create a file named WindowsTimeFixUTC.reg with the following contents and then double click on it to merge the contents with the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
     "RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

**Note**: Windows Time service will still write local time to the RTC regardless of the registry setting above on shutdown, so it is handy to disable Windows Time service with this command (if time sync is still required while in Windows use any third-party time sync solution):

```
sc config w32time start= disabled
```

Reversing the change

You can create a file with the following contents and then double-click it to merge in the original changes, as above:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
     "RealTimeIsUniversal"=-
```

If Windows Time service was disabled, enable it again with the command:

```
sc config w32time start= demand
```

**Make Linux use 'Local' time**

To tell your Ubuntu system that the hardware clock is set to 'local' time:

1. edit /etc/default/rcS
2. add or change the following section:

   ```
   # Set UTC=yes if your hardware clock is set to UTC (GMT)
   UTC=no
   ```